# How to calculate acceleration due to pressure difference?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure, acceleration

[image]

Like in this situation can acceleration be calculated due to pressure difference considering the gravitational acceleration will act downwards.

Comment: The answer to this question is "yes," but can you please elaborate further on your doubt?

Comment: The doubt is whether in this situation the the gravitational acceleration will cause notable hinderance for the upward flow of water to low pressure area,and how much hinderance will it cause ?

Comment: I’m having trouble reading your handwriting on the figure.  And what is that vertical line on the bottom?